Expo 51 SpalshScreen white screen, preventAutoHideAsync not working
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { RootSiblingParent } from "react-native-root-siblings";
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { View } from "react-native";

import { useColorScheme } from "@/components/useColorScheme";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistor, store } from "@/store/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "(screens)",
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
  .then(() => console.log("SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() succeeded"))
  .catch(console.warn);

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        console.log("Starting resource loading...");
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
        await Font.loadAsync({
          SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
          ...FontAwesome.font,
        });
        console.log("Fonts loaded");
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        console.log("Resource loading complete");
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      console.log("App is ready, hiding splash screen...");
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      console.log("Splash screen hidden");
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

    console.log("App is not ready, returning null");
    return null;
  }

  console.log("Rendering RootLayoutNav");
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <RootLayoutNav />
    </View>
  );
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootSiblingParent>
          <ThemeProvider
            value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
          >
            <Stack>
              <Stack.Screen name="(screens)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="modal" options={{ presentation: "modal" }} />
            </Stack>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </RootSiblingParent>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}


for 4 secs or whatever sec i use timeout, white screen is seen. SplashScreen hides before hideAsync() is called. In expo 50 this was not the issue but now I have this issue how to solve this?
I tried downgrading just expo-splash-screen but nothing changed. Can't downgrade expo because some of packages are alraedy deprecated.
